# How to remove hash from url angular app?

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, hash, html5mode

It may be the duplicate question. but i have tried so many solutions,no answer  work for me. I am using ui-router for angular web app.
I am using apache2 server to serve the angular app. I am using Ubuntu.
My project code is inside of the folder \var\www\html\myapp 
here *myapp* is the my application folder.
I have tried the following 
**1** adding `<base href="/myapp/">` to the head tag 
**2** adding `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`  or `$locationProvider.html5Mode({    enabled: true,    requireBase: false});`
(tried with both separately) 
**3** adding the `.htaccess` file with the following content

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

and some other content for .htaccess file which i got from google to serve the path.
I have tried putting .htaccess file inside \var\www\html\ as well as \var\www\html\myapp.
It will remove the hash from the url, but when i clicked refresh ,it will show *not found*. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this in `.htaccess` file under `\var\www\html\myapp` :**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

**In `index.html` head section :**

```
<base href="/myapp/">
```

**In app config :**

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});

/* Records full path */
$analyticsProvider.withBase(true);
```